# How can I make the neck of this desk light?

Tags: mesh

How can I make the neck of the light? For the flexible part, I think that a normal map would look weird because it is circular.

[image: It's a desk lamp with a long, bumpy neck]

Comment: Amazing answers

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Modeling

Create a bezier curve tracing the neck of the lamp. Model a small part of the neck and array it using the bezier curve as a *Fit Type*. This will repeat the part till it fits the length of the curve.

[image: Array]

Then using *Curve Deform* modifier, deform the output over the curve.

[image: Curve]

Now scale the object and **apply the scale** to get the required amount of repetitions.

## Procedural Shading

If you want to implement the bumps in shading stage. Solidify the curve and and enable *Use UV For Mapping*.

[image: Use UV]

Then for the material, use the $x$ component of the UV to compute strips like pattern where the value $20$ controls the number of repetitions, $0.17$ controls the width of engraving and $0.2$ controls the relative slope of the transition.

[image: Shading]

You can now use this as bump of displacement for the material.

Answer (score 7):

If you want a screwed lamp neck, you can start with a deformed half circle and use a *screw modifier* and a *curve modifier*.

[image]

- Add a circle
- Remove half of it
- Deform the remaining shape to model the mesh profile
- Shift it from its center
- Add a *screw modifier* (see parameters above)
- Then add a *curve modifier*

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can use an Array modifier and a Curve modifier :[image]

Array Modifier will duplicate your base object (the one on the left). If Fit Type is set to Fit Curve, it will duplicate it until it reach the length of the specified Curve.

Curve Modifier will deform the array along the specified Curve. Object and Curve origin/orientation should match, or you won't get a good result.